# How to pass anonymous property via lambda to a generic function?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, lambda

I want to pass anonymous property using lambda to a generic function and access it there.
And how Do I access the property inside.

```
using (CommentsRepository commentsRepository = new CommentsRepository())
{
   var comments = commentsRepository.GetAllComments();

   Foo<Comment>(comments, 0,com=>com.ID); //Comment is an  EF entity
}

public static void Foo<TObject>(IEnumerable<TObject> list, int iCurID, <Func<TObject, TProperty> property) where TObject : class
{       
   foreach (var cat in list.Where(/*How to access the property*/==iCurID)
   {
          int x = cat.property;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just call the delegate:

```
public static void Foo<TObject>
    (IEnumerable<TObject> list, 
     int iCurID,
     Func<TObject, int> propertySelector) where TObject : class
{       
   foreach (var cat in list.Where(x => propertySelector(x) == iCurID))
   {

   }
}
```

Note that I had to change the type of the delegate to `Func<TObject, int>` as otherwise you couldn't compare it with `iCurID`.

Comment: what is propertySelector? you mean property(x)?

Comment: @urker: Sorry, I meant to change the name of the parameter - personally I'd also change "iCurID" which is reasonably meaningless too.

Comment: @urker: It's not clear what you mean by "how do I access the property inside". What are you trying to do? Inside where?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, inside loop! get the property value: int x = cat.property;

Comment: @urker: You already know the value of the property - `iCurID` - otherwise it wouldn't have passed the `Where` clause to start with.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, never mind i got it (there was another property that i didn't specify) I access via: myOtherpropertySelector(cat)